# Update AlpineJS Bind Data from outside

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Here I set x-data in every single element to install a site

```
@foreach ($websites as $item)
<tr class="class" x-data="{ install: false }">
<!-- Content -->
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Inside the content there are an install button which run javascript

```
function doInstall(websiteId){
    const url = '/website/install/'+websiteId;
    const successCallback = function(response){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("span[id=status]").html(response.message);
            if(typeof(response.finish)=='undefined'){
                doInstall(websiteId);
            }
            else{
                // Set back Install to false
            }
        },1000);
    }
    const res = CallAjax({
        url: url,
        successCallback: successCallback,
    });
}
```

I combine JQuery there since I need the ajax to make an installer which automate call when it is success. Once backend set finish then it will set back Install to false in Alpine

How can I do that?